# SQLServer JDBC Driver]Object has been closed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, java

I had few queries in code which were running in loop. They all were wrapped inside a code function. There were frequent deadlock with the queries. Because I do not understand the logic too well, I was tasked to take all that code logic to a SP. I used cursors for loop. I then changed cursors to table variables. 
SP works decent when run from DB. But when I implement the SP call in code, it throws this error

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Object has been closed.
```

It shows error running a random query (different on different times)

```
coldfusion.tagext.sql.QueryTag.startQueryExecution(QueryTag.java:866)
coldfusion.tagext.sql.QueryTag.doEndTag(QueryTag.java:768)
cfApplication2ecfc7425840$funcGETSYSTEMGLOBALS.runFunction(D:\dev.insco\Application.cfc:532)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:492)
coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:425)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:388)
coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:339)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:234)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:650)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:439)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:409)
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:3097)
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:3074)
cfsystem2dglobals2ecfm1526892961.runPage(D:\dev.insco\system-globals.cfm:64)
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:253)
coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.handlePageInvoke(IncludeTag.java:737)
coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:573)
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:3696)
cfAusum2ecfc700418986._factor0(D:\dev.insco\Components\Ausum.cfc:25)
cfAusum2ecfc700418986.runPage(D:\dev.insco\Components\Ausum.cfc:1)
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:253)
coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.resolveComponentHelper(TemplateProxyFactory.java:542)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.resolveName(TemplateProxyFactory.java:251)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.resolveName(TemplateProxyFactory.java:162)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.resolveName(TemplateProxyFactory.java:152)
coldfusion.cfc.ComponentProxyFactory.getProxy(ComponentProxyFactory.java:57)
coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:6354)
coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:6373)
cfApplication2ecfc7425840$funcONERROR.runFunction(D:\dev.insco\Application.cfc:295)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:492)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:425)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:388)
coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:339)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:234)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:650)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:439)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:409)
coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.invoke(AppEventInvoker.java:114)
coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onError(AppEventInvoker.java:497)
coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:555)
coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:153)
coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94)
coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:60)
coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:219)
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor940.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filterchain.WrappedFilterChain.doFilter(WrappedFilterChain.java:134)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.doNext(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:764)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.doHttpServletRequest(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:344)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.doFusionRequest(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:207)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.handle(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:801)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorCoreFilter.doFilter(FusionReactorCoreFilter.java:36)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor939.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filterchain.WrappedFilterChain.doFilter(WrappedFilterChain.java:71)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor938.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.agent.filter.FusionReactorStaticFilter.doFilter(FusionReactorStaticFilter.java:54)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.agent.pointcuts.NewFilterChainPointCut$1.invoke(NewFilterChainPointCut.java:41)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:363)
org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:507)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused By

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Object has been closed.

macromedia.jdbc.sqlserverbase.ddcw.b(Unknown Source)
macromedia.jdbc.sqlserverbase.ddcw.a(Unknown Source)
macromedia.jdbc.sqlserverbase.ddcv.b(Unknown Source)
macromedia.jdbc.sqlserverbase.ddcv.a(Unknown Source)
macromedia.jdbc.sqlserverbase.BaseConnection.getMetaData(Unknown Source)
coldfusion.server.j2ee.sql.JRunConnection.getMetaData(JRunConnection.java:508)
coldfusion.server.j2ee.sql.JRunConnectionHandle.getMetaData(JRunConnectionHandle.java:137)
coldfusion.sql.Executive.executeQuery(Executive.java:1302)
coldfusion.sql.Executive.executeQuery(Executive.java:1281)
coldfusion.sql.Executive.executeQuery(Executive.java:1211)
coldfusion.sql.SqlImpl.execute(SqlImpl.java:406)
coldfusion.tagext.sql.QueryTag.executeQuery(QueryTag.java:1181)
coldfusion.tagext.sql.QueryTag.startQueryExecution(QueryTag.java:815)
coldfusion.tagext.sql.QueryTag.doEndTag(QueryTag.java:768)
cfApplication2ecfc7425840$funcGETSYSTEMGLOBALS.runFunction(D:\dev.myApp\Application.cfc:532)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:492)
coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:425)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:388)
coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:339)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:234)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:650)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:439)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:409)
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:3097)
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:3074)
cfsystem2dglobals2ecfm1526892961.runPage(D:\dev.myApp\system-globals.cfm:64)
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:253)
coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.handlePageInvoke(IncludeTag.java:737)
coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:573)
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:3696)
cfMyApp2ecfc700418986._factor0(D:\dev.myApp\Components\MyApp.cfc:25)
cfMyApp2ecfc700418986.runPage(D:\dev.myApp\Components\MyApp.cfc:1)
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:253)
coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.resolveComponentHelper(TemplateProxyFactory.java:542)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.resolveName(TemplateProxyFactory.java:251)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.resolveName(TemplateProxyFactory.java:162)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.resolveName(TemplateProxyFactory.java:152)
coldfusion.cfc.ComponentProxyFactory.getProxy(ComponentProxyFactory.java:57)
coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:6354)
coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:6373)
cfApplication2ecfc7425840$funcONERROR.runFunction(D:\dev.myApp\Application.cfc:295)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:492)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:425)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:388)
coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:339)
coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:234)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:650)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:439)
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:409)
coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.invoke(AppEventInvoker.java:114)
coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onError(AppEventInvoker.java:497)
coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:555)
coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:153)
coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94)
coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:60)
coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:219)
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor940.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filterchain.WrappedFilterChain.doFilter(WrappedFilterChain.java:134)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.doNext(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:764)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.doHttpServletRequest(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:344)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.doFusionRequest(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:207)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.handle(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:801)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorCoreFilter.doFilter(FusionReactorCoreFilter.java:36)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor939.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filterchain.WrappedFilterChain.doFilter(WrappedFilterChain.java:71)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor938.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.agent.filter.FusionReactorStaticFilter.doFilter(FusionReactorStaticFilter.java:54)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.agent.pointcuts.NewFilterChainPointCut$1.invoke(NewFilterChainPointCut.java:41)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:363)
org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:507)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. We appreciate your participation. Please consider reading the following article: _[How do I ask a good question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (Help Centre)_. Currently your question is missing a full explanation (missing details) and might be closed as [**unclear what you're asking**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). Please [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/238536/edit) your question and add more details, e.g. the (java) code, the stored procedure, ...

Comment: We can't answer questions about code we cannot see but make sure you have `SET NOCOUNT ON;` in the proc code. That will suppress `DONE_IN_PROC` messages (row counts) that may confuse client code that isn't coded to handle multiple result sets and cause symptoms like this.